# Java: Read an unknown number of properties

Tags: java, properties

I have a Java properties file defined as something like:

```
Property.1=value1
Property.2=value2
...
```

There could be any number of properties here.

I am familiar with how to read and use Java Properties, but I am not sure how I would code reading properties when I don't know the number of them. My idea of pseudo-code would be something like:

```
// Somehow get the number of properties
for (int i=0; i<properties.size(); i++ {
   prop.getProperty("Property"+i);
...
}
```

Does anyone know how to read a variable number of properties?

Comment: Except it should be (i + 1) when getting the property, this code seems OK to me. Why would you want anything different?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your properties are numbered sequentially as your example suggests:

```
int i = 1;
String p;
while ((p = prop.getProperty("Property."+i)) != null) {
  // property #i has value p
  i++;
}
```

Comment: This assumes they're already in the system. I believe the constraint is how to get them into the system from the properties file.

Comment: Thanks, this works nicely. I should have thought of it. It's simple and does the trick. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `java.util.Properties` class has the ability to load from an input stream.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29

Simply pass a new `Properties` object the input stream from the file and let it roll.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at Commons Collections class [ExtendedProperties](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/ExtendedProperties.html#subset%28java.lang.String%29) and it's method [subset](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/ExtendedProperties.html#subset%28java.lang.String%29)

That allows you to get all properties with given prefix ('Property.' for example)